# I need to run some C++ code in javascript

Tags: javascript, c++

I need to run some C++ code in javascript. The code is long and actually kinda heavy, and it's slow in javascript. I'm hoping I'll have better results in C++, because it's faster. I can convert to C++ pretty easily, I just need to know how to run this code. And if it doesn't work, it'll be great knowledge anyway and a good way to spend my time in quarantine.

Comment: The way to run C++ code in Javascript is to... convert your C++ code to Javascript and then run that code. I'm serious. Web browsers won't let you run C++ code for good reasons.

Comment: NodeJS or client-side?

Comment: Well I already mentioned that I want this to be more efficient than running javascript, and I already have the code in javascript, I want to run it in C++ to be more efficient.

Comment: If you want to do this in a browser, the answer is probably ... use WASM? If it's on the server you've got a lot more flexibility.

Comment: And, what is this piece of code doing that takes so long?

Comment: No I don't have to do it in a browser, I run it on my server.